# Particular solution of $\sin^2(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation:
$$y'' + y = \sin^2(x)$$ 
and to solve it I need to use variation of parameters and therefore I need to find the form of the particular solution.

What is your way of finding the form of the solution?

Any suggestions on how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it $\sin^2 x$ or $\sin(2x)$? If $\sin(2x)$ then try for $a\sin(2x)$. If $\sin^2 x$, use a double-angle identity.

Comment: I mean $sin^2(x)$

Comment: It might be easier to write $\sin^2 x = {1 \over 2} (1-\cos ( 2x))$.

Comment: the form of the particular solution should be $A\sin(2x)+B\cos(2x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you mentioned you want to use the method of "variation of parameters"! So solution of the homogeneous differential equation gives the solutions $y_1 =\cos x $, $ y_2 =\sin x  $ with ronskian $W(y_1,y_2) =1 $. The particular solution is given by

$$ y_p = -y_1\int \frac{y_2 \sin^2(x) } {W(y_1,y_2)}+ y_2\int \frac{y_1 \sin^2(x) } {W(y_1,y_2)}$$

$$ = -\cos x\int { \sin x \sin^2(x) } + \sin x\int { \cos x \sin^2(x) }  .$$

You should finish evaluating the above integrals.

Comment: Is this a formula you can use to find the particular solution for all differential equations?

Comment: @fadaes: Yes you can apply it. But sometimes it is hard to evaluate the integrals.

Comment: Okay, I'll keep that in mind, thanks!

Comment: The Wronskian is $W(\cos(t),\sin(t))=1$.

Comment: @jdods: It is corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

My way: Use the fact that $\sin^2 x=\frac{1-\cos 2x}{2}$. For the  $-\frac{\cos(2x)}{2}$ part, use $a\cos(2x)$ for suitable $a$. And for the $\frac{1}{2}$ part, use $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

The right-hand side can be reduced to standard form: $\sin^2x=\dfrac{1-\cos 2x}2$. $\cos 2x$ is not a solution of the homogeneous equation, and we know in such a case there's a particular solution of the form:
$$A\sin 2x+B\cos 2x.$$

The simplest way to compute it to use the fact that $\cos 2x$ is the real part of $\mathrm e^{2\mkern1mu\mathrm i x}$. So you first solve for right-hand side $=\mathrm e^{2\mkern1mu\mathrm i x}$, then take the real part of the solution. You'll find
$$y_0=\frac x2+\frac16\,\cos 2x.$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the technique [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1158877/a-different-variation-of-parameters-technique):
$$Y_p=y_h\int y_h^{-2} W_0 \left(\int y_h W_0^{-1} g \ dt\right) \ dt$$
where 
$$W_{0}=\exp\left(-{\int p \ dt}\right).$$
So $W_{0}=\exp\left(-{\int 0 \ dt}\right)=1$. Using $y_h=\cos t$ will make the integral easier, hence:
$$
\begin{aligned}
Y_p&=\cos (t) \int \frac{1}{\cos^2(t)} \left(\int \cos (t) \sin^2(t) \ dt\right) \ dt \\
&=\cos (t) \int \frac{1}{\cos^2(t)} \frac{\sin^3(t)}{3}\ dt \\
&=\cos (t) \int \frac{\sin^3(t)}{3\cos^2(t)} \ dt \\
&=\cos (t) \int \frac{1-\cos^2(t)}{3\cos^2(t)} \sin(t)\ dt \\
&= \frac{\cos (t)}{3} \left(\int \frac{\sin (t)}{\cos^2(t)}\ dt-\int\sin(t)\ dt \right) \\
&=\frac{\cos (t)}{3}\left(\frac{1}{\cos(t)}+ \cos(t)\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{3}\left(1+ \cos^2(t)\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Alternatively, I would prefer to write the solution as
$$Y_p=\frac{1}{3}\left(2- \sin^2(t)\right).$$

One could also find the solution by the integral:
$$
Y_p=\sin (t) \int \frac{1}{\sin^2(t)} \left(\int \sin^3(t) \ dt\right) \ dt.
$$
However, I think this one takes a little more work.