# Solving 2nd order ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

How would you this ODE: 
$$x''+x+\cos^3t=0$$
The homogenous solution is $x=C\cos t$ so $C\cos t$ is term is part of the solution. But how would you go from there?

Comment: What method have you been taught to find a particular solution?

Comment: tried every methods we taught, won't work. (Integration factor, characteristic polynomials, exact)

Comment: See what I added in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

$\bf hint:$  use $$4\cos^3 t = 3\cos t + \cos 3t$$ and look for a particular solution of the form $$ x = At\sin t + B \cos 3t.$$

Comment: This is not sufficient since each trigonometric function stands for two exponentials. Thus the general ansatz for the particular solution is $t(A\cos t+B\sin t)+C\cos3t+D\sin3t$.

Comment: @LutzL, you will find that $B = 0.$  no need to make it more complicated than necessary.

Comment: That may be true, but one should then be able to justify this specialization with some symmetry arguments. In other second order ODE with this inhomogeneity, all four terms will occur.

Comment: @LutzL, it is not may be true; it is true. the whole point of ansatz is trial and error. if you already know what is the point of adding up nonsense.

Comment: No, there is nothing trial and error with this ansatz. It works if and only if the inhomogeneity is of the form sum of polynomial times exponential. And in this case there are very stringent rules on how to build each term of the particular solution for each addens of the inhomogeneity.

Comment: @LutzL thanks for the answer, but how would you arrive on that four term answer? without guessing?

Comment: The term $p(t)e^{\lambda t}$ in the inhomogeneity gives a term $t^\mu q(t)e^{\lambda t}$ where $\deg q=\deg p$ and $\mu$ is the multiplicity of $\lambda$ as root of the characteristic polynomial, i.e. in general $0$. A combination of complex $\lambda$ and $\bar \lambda$ results from and in trigonometric functions in the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of the ode

$$ x''+x=0 $$

should be

$$ x(t) = c_1\cos(t)+c_2\sin(t). $$

**Added:** For the particular solution you can use [variation of parameters method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1133525/particular-solution-of-sin2x/1133561#1133561).